# VBA: Replacing value in sheet 1 with value in sheet 2 based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

So I have put comments in which should help explain what I am trying to achieve with my code, but essentially I have a column in sheet 1 with a list of names which will change every time I use this code, and I have a column in sheet 2 with a list of all the names which may be in sheet 1, think of sheet 2 as a master list with information I already have.

I am wanting to replace the information in column Z in sheet 1 with the information I may already have from column J in sheet 2, but only if I already have that information, so I am testing each row's name in sheet 1 against the names I have in my master list in sheet 2, and if the names match then I want to code to copy across the information from column J in sheet 2 to column z in sheet 1.

The names are in column G for sheet 1, and column D for sheet 2

```
Sub H_Replace_Other()

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

'Ranges
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range

'Cells
Dim options_name As Range, info_name As Range, options_other As Range, info_other As Range

Set sh1 = Worksheets("options")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("building info")

'Define dynamic ranges which I want to test
Set r1 = sh1.Range("G3")
Set r1 = sh1.Range(r1, r1.End(xlDown))
Set r2 = sh2.Range("D3")
Set r2 = sh2.Range(r2, r2.End(xlDown))

'Define dynamic range with values I want to replace
Set r3 = sh1.Range("Z3")
Set r3 = sh1.Range(r3, r3.End(xlDown))

'Define dynamic range with info I want use
Set r4 = sh2.Range("J3")
Set r4 = sh2.Range(r4, r4.End(xlDown))

'Define cell I want to replace
Set options_other = Cells(options_name, 26)

'Define cell with info I want to use
Set info_other = Cells(info_name, 10)

'Test condition
For Each options_name In r1
    For Each info_name In r2
        If options_name = info_name Then
        'Replace value
            options_other.Value = info_other.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next options_name

End Sub
```

My many thanks to you if you can help me out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Any reason why you cannot use Worksheet Formulas? Like XLOOKUP, VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup

[image]
[image]

**Excel Formula Using `INDEX/MATCH`**

- According to the data in the screenshots, in cell `Z3` of worksheet `Options`, you could use the formula

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX('Building Info'!J$3:J$12,MATCH($G3,'Building Info'!$D$3:$D$12,0)),"")
  ```

  and copy down to `Z12`.

**VBA Using `Application.Match`**

- To keep it simple and more educational at this stage, no arrays (to increase efficiency) are used.
- By using `Application.Match`, we have got rid of the inner loop which is usually severely slowing down the operation.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookup()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Building Info"
    Const slCol As String = "D" ' 2. ... here... (Lookup Column)
    Const svCol As String = "J" ' 3. ... and return this... (Value Column)
    Const sfRow As Long = 3 ' First Row
    
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Options"
    Const dlCol As String = "G" ' 1. Lookup this... (Lookup Column)
    Const dvCol As String = "Z" ' 4. ... here. (Value Column)
    Const dfRow As Long = 3 ' First Row
    Const NoMatchValue As Variant = Empty
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long ' Last Row
    slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim slrg As Range ' ('D3:DslRow')
    Set slrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol), sws.Cells(slRow, slCol))
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol) ' ('J3:JslRow')
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long ' Last Row
    dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dlrg As Range ' ('G3:GdlRow')
    Set dlrg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol), dws.Cells(dlRow, dlCol))
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol) ' ('Z3:ZdlRow')
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim srIndex As Variant ' could also be an error value hence 'As Variant'
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant ' could be anything reasonable hence 'As Variant'
    Dim drIndex As Long ' is always a number hence 'As Long'
    Dim MatchFound As Boolean
    
    For Each dCell In dlrg.Cells
        drIndex = drIndex + 1
        dValue = dCell.Value
        If Not IsError(dValue) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(dValue) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                ' Attempt to find a match.
                srIndex = Application.Match(dValue, slrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(srIndex) Then ' is a match i.e. is a number
                    MatchFound = True
                'Else ' is not a match i.e. is an error value; do nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If MatchFound Then
            dvrg.Cells(drIndex).Value = svrg.Cells(srIndex).Value
            MatchFound = False ' reset variable
        Else
            dvrg.Cells(drIndex).Value = NoMatchValue
            ' no need to reset variable; already 'MatchFound = False'
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    MsgBox "VBA Lookup finished.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks heaps, really appreciate the clear explanation and comments. Wasn't aware of the index function either but the VBA code will save me those precious seconds haha. Now to try and expand this to other value and destination coloumns too! Thanks again